# How to pass php values to javascript then to ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I am echoing data into a table with values from my database.  It looks like this:

```
<?php
  //mysqli_num_rows function
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array //I know this may be wrong, but that's not the point
  echo "<tr><td>".$somedata."</td></tr>";
?>
```

So the value of this table row will be displayed based on how much data is in the database.  I want to asynchronously update the page, for example the user wants to delete this from the DB.  How can I pass this value to `javascript` with an `onClick` function?  Or is there another way?  If I have a link to delete in the table like:

```
<td><a onClick="delete(ThisValueOfThisTableRow)">Delete</a></td>
```

And in `javascript` or `jQuery` I want to find this value and set it to a variable, then pass it as:

```
var some_value = //get this value
.ajax{
  url: "somephpfile.php"
  data:{some_value:value}
}
```

I think this would be helpful to anyone if they a responsive member page.  Please help out!

Comment: The value of your delete link should be printed in your php loop.

Comment: It is...the problem is passing it to javascript and setting it to a value so then it can be passed to ajax.

Comment: you could set an appropriate piece of the data (row id, etc.) as part of the tag in question in `rel`, `id`, or something similar. then, in jquery, on click you just grab that value, throw it the `data` object you pass to ajax, and then boom you're good to go

Comment: @user2025469 By printing it from your php you are passing it to the javascript function `delete` and inside that function you will be able to use that value.

Comment: so, for example as the <td id="something">, in jQuery I could just do some_value = $(#something).val(); and then throw that into data{}?  It would grab the php value?

Comment: not quite. $.val() will grab the value of a form's input (textarea, dropdown, etc). with your php example above in mind you'd want to use something like $.text() to grab what's contained in the `<td>`

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this:

```
<?php
  //mysqli_num_rows function
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?=$somedata;?></td>
<td><a href='#' class='delete-btn' id='row-<?=$someID;?>'>Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<?
}//end while
?>
```

and then for the js event

```
$('.delete-btn').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  id = id.split("-");
  data = { "id" : id[1] }
  //your ajax here, pass in your data obj
});
```

best of luck-

Comment: yes. the point of concern for you is the `id` or other attribute put on the element for you to be able to get to in your jQuery, pass to AJAX, and finally to the server to process accordingly.

Comment: This is driving me crazy.  I have echo'<td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="test()">Test</a></td>.  I have a test.js file and in the file I have function test(){alert("hello");}  When I click test, nothing happens...what's wrong with this?  I want to put the variables into the test function later and set it as a variable, then split it.  But i can't even get the alert to work.

Comment: are you planning on doing strict js or using a library like jquery? if you're having trouble with an alert then i imagine the ajax part will be loads of fun for you :) a quick jquery based solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jbly/6Q2M2/

Comment: I can use either JS or jQuery.  I've used ajax before and that's the frustrating thing.  If I pass a full php file with php variables attached as a href, I can call a pop up window and pass the variables to php through JS and pop up.  But right now I can't even call a simple alert with onclick...driving me crazy!

Comment: Yeah, I saw it.  I just have a quick questions for you.  If I can pass the variable as an href to a pop up window and the values are displayed fully in the search bar, then shouldn't I be able to pass them in javascript ajax, not jquery, as ajax.send("id="+id+"&somethingelse="+somethingelse);???  Without having to declare them in javascript, only passed along in the onclick function? I found sample codes that do this onclick within php...

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
    echo '<tr><td><a onclick="delete_row(' . $row['id'] . ')">delete row</a></td></tr>';
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function delete_row( id ) {
    alert( id ); //To show you are getting the id remove this for production

    //ajax goes here
}
```